# Find $y(x)$ from this equation $y-3\ln|y|=4\ln|x|+4k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find $y(x)$ from this equation?
$$y-3\ln|y|=4\ln|x|+4k$$

---

I tried raising both sides to the power of $e$ [ed.: exponentiating them] but couldn't get the answer out.

Comment: Where is it from? What are your thoughts on this? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried raising both sides to the power of $e$ but couldn't get the answer out.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, unless you use the Lambert's $W$ function.

Setting $y=-3w$, the equation becomes

$$-3w-3\ln|3w|=4\ln|x|+4k,$$
or
$$w+\ln|w|=-\frac43(\ln|x|+k)-\ln3,$$
and taking the exponential,
$$we^w=\pm\frac13|x|^{-4/3}e^{-4k/3},$$
so that 
$$y=-3W(\pm\frac13|x|^{-4/3}e^{-4k/3}).$$
This is enough to prove that there is no solution in elementary functions.

Comment: @Dr.MV: you don't seem to be familiar with Lambert's function. I have added the explicit solution.

Comment: I am familiar with that function.  Your answer is fine! +1

Comment: Read the edited post

Comment: disregard. I deleted